# How to tap on a UIImageView in unit testing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a UIImageView that is located on the left side of a navigation bar. How would i go about tapping on the imageView in XCTestCase?

Comment: What do you mean with a `UIImageView` that is located on the left side of a navigation bar? It's a `UIBarButtonItem` with an image?

Comment: yes exactly! and it has gesture recognizer turned on

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, supposing you have an `UIBarButtonItem` with an `UIImage` and you've defined some `@IBAction` for when you make click in your `UIBarButtonItem` you can simulate a tap inside your `UIBarButtonItem` like in this way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Send the the action to invoke the target specified when you make your @IBAction or define a target manually.
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(barButtonItem.action, to: barButtonItem.target, from: nil, forEvent: nil)
}  

// @IBAction defined using Interface Builder
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

In the above code when the `UIViewController` loads you will see the output `"Tapped"` in your console. The same logic can be translated to your unit test when you initialize the `UIViewController` you want to test.

Once you have defined an `UIBarBUttonItem` you don't have to define an `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the `UIImage` inside it to know when it's tapped.

I hope this help you.